# receive file object or file path

Tags: python

I know that in static languages it's always better to receive a file object rather than a string representing a path (from a software design standpoint). However, in a dynamic language like python  where you can't see the type of the variable, what's the "correct" way to pass a file?

Isn't it problematic passing the function object since you need to remember to close it afterwards (which you probably won't since you can't see the type)?

Comment: type(myObject) returns the type of myObject. type(myObject) is file returns True, if myObject is a file object.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would be using the with statement whenever you open a file, so closing will be handled by that.

```
with open('filepath', 'r') as f:
    myfunc(f)

otherstuff() # f is now closed
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. He is not asking how to open a file, rather how to pass an object around.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It seems to me that at least one of the things he is asking is how to deal with closing a file object once it is passed to you. My point is that the with block should usually be handling closing the file for you, so the problem of closing files that he posed shouldn't be an issue. I agree with your later answer that duck-typing is potentially part of the solution, but when possible the load should be passed off onto the with manager.

Comment: That's just an anecdotal question - I believe he is asking _"if I can't check for the type, how am I suppose for - for example - do a file operation like close it?"_.

Answer (score 1):

> However, in a dynamic language like python where you can't see the
>   type of the variable, **what's the "correct" way to pass a file?**

The short answer is - you don't.

In most object oriented languages, there is an object contract which guarantees that if the object has a method `quack`, it knows how to quack.  Some languages are very strict in enforcing this contract (Java, for example) and others not so much.

In the end it comes down to one of Python's principles [`EAFP`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

> **E** asier to **a** sk for **f** orgiveness than **p** ermission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.

LBYL = Look Before You Leap

What this means is that if your method is expecting a "file" (and you state this in your documentation), assume you are being passed a "file like object". Try to execute a file operation on the object (like `read()` or `close()`) and then catch the exception if its raised.

One of the main points of the EAFP approach is that you may be getting passed an object that works like a file, in other words - the caller knows what they are doing. So if you spend time checking for exact types, you'll have code that isn't working when it should. Now the burden is on the caller to meet your "object contract"; but what if they are not working with files but with an in-memory buffer (which have the same methods as files)? Or a request object (again, have the same file-like methods). You can't possibly check for all these variations in your code.

This is the preferred approach - instead of the LBYL approach, which would be type checking first.

So, if your method's documentation states that its expecting a file object, it should work with any object that is "file like", but when someone passes it a string to a file path, your method should raise an appropriate exception.

Also, and more importantly - you should avoid closing the object in your method; because it may not be a "file" like explained earlier. However if you absolutely must, make sure the documentation for your method states this very clearly.

Here is an example:

```
def my_method(fobj):
    ''' Writes to fobj, which is any file-like object,
        and returns the object '''
    try:
        fobj.write('The answer is: {}\n'.format(42))
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        raise TypeError('Expected file-like object')
    return fobj
```

Comment: This makes sense. But it still results in "ugly" code. Having to look up where an object was created is not fun. I guess this is the curse of dynamic languages.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point; you don't look up where the object was created. In fact, that's the whole idea in that you don't care - as long as the object provides the methods that you expect; in your case `.close()`, `.open()`, etc. then you call those methods and leave it up to the object to know what to actually do.

Comment: That's true. But it will require a lot of documentation. Otherwise I'll come back to this 3 months from now not knowing if `file` is a string or a file object.

Answer (score 1):

Pass file object just like any other type.

```
def f(myfile):
    myfile.write('asdf')

ofs = open(filepath, 'w') # ofs is file object
f(ofs) # passes file object
ofs.close()
```

Can also use closure.

```
def f():
    return open(filepath, 'w') # returns file object

ofs = f()
ofs.write('something')
ofs.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file objects in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).  When they are (automatically) garbage collected, the file will be closed for you.

> File objects are implemented using C’s stdio package and can be created with the built-in open() function.

Comment: So I don't have to worry about closing files myself?

Comment: That's correct. You can call f.close() if you want, in order to free up resources earlier.  But if you don't, it will automatically be closed when the file object referenced by f is garbage collected.

Comment: @AndrewChi - That's interesting. Why close a file then? It seems silly to even worry about it.

Comment: Your system can run out of file descriptors if you leave enough files open. Say you want to search for the string "foo" in a directory containing 100 thousand files. You don't want to do it in a way that has every file open simultaneously (e.g., keeping a list of all 100k file objects).